# How can I boot into GUI after changing the default user (no longer working)?

Tags: raspbian, boot, raspi-config

I'm at wits end with this. I have followed the instructions at: [Boot into the GUI after changing default user](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/12538/boot-into-the-gui-after-changing-default-user) to change the user that automatically logs on in GUI mode. It no longer seems to work with the 'raspi-config' changes made to Raspbian Jessie. I have followed the steps in that post to the letter including the changes to '/etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf'. If 'autologin-user=pi' is set, then all is well and the GUI boots automatically into user 'pi'. BUT, if I change the autologin user in lightdm.conf to ANY other user, upon reboot I get a graphical screen requesting login userid and password. The other users I created have ALL the same privileges and group associations as 'pi' and I can manually login to them with no problem.

In short, since the changes to Jessie, given the above instructions, ONLY user 'pi' seems able to autologin.

Please forgive any breaches of etiquette as I am a new user here at the forum. I originally posted this as a comment to the original question and it was deleted. I was asked to "ask a question" so here I am trying to do so.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks, Daniel S.